# Extra padding on Chrome and Safari around LI items

Tags: css, html

In the nav bar on this site, we're having a problem with padding on the li items in the nav bar. 
http://www.wbbearonline.com/

In Chrome and Safari, the left padding on each li item says 10, but it's actually adding a couple extra pixels (making padding 12 or 13).

Firefox and IE9 show the correct 10px.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you set the margin, too? The default margin could differ between browsers.

Comment: The links look the same to me in chrome and firefox - are you sure its not the 3px padding that only appears on unvisited links that is causing the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireFox is not applying the a:link css property to links that have been visited, therefore those links do not receive the 3px padding.  Chrome **is** applying it however.

To fix it, try just changing your css "a:link" rule to "a".

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Forgot about that extra padding from before we switched to li's. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There might be margins or pads inherited from parent items, have you tried a [css reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) file(Although it may be a bit extreme for this instance)? Or setting the pads/margins further up the tree to 0?